# Python parsing query from dynamo - TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am getting an error when trying to parse data i have received from dynamo, to replicate the error i have save what i receive as a variable below `failed_requests` I am getting the same error

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

```
def myfunction():
    failed_requests = [{'payload': '{"claimNumber": "9000005", "dateEntered": "2010-09-17T13:08:02", "fileNoteId": "08D8447A", "fileName": "responseUint.pdf.pdf", "fileExtension": ".pdf", "categoryCode": "6a5f9", "subCategoryCode": "13", "noteText": "INCOMING -20- aug demo", "dateCreated": "2020-08-19T20:03:35.1986907", "createdBy": "Mick", "dateUpdated": "2020-08-19T20:03:35.1986907", "updatedBy": "Mick", "attachmentId": "0xc2d174150x2625", "fileDescription": "test-FN-attachment-1-20-Aug", "authorId": "35651784012", "serviceFromDate": "2020-08-05T00:00:00", "serviceToDate": "2020-08-20T00:00:00", "dateOnDocument": "2020-08-11T00:00:00", "status": "ffe1c"}', 'filenote_id': '08D8447A', 'processed': 'false'}]

    print("ALL FAILED REQUESTS ------->" + str(failed_requests))

    for failed_request in failed_requests:
        print(
            failed_requests["filenote_id"],
            ":",
            failed_requests["payload"],
            failed_request["processed"],
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myfunction()
```

Comment: I didn't see the `file_note_id` in your `failed_requests`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's typo in the for-loop, `failed_requests` should be `failed_request` without `s`. Also `file_note_id` key doesn't exist in your dictionary, but `filenote_id` does:

```
def myfunction():
    failed_requests = [{'payload': '{"claimNumber": "9000005", "dateEntered": "2010-09-17T13:08:02", "fileNoteId": "08D8447A", "fileName": "responseUint.pdf.pdf", "fileExtension": ".pdf", "categoryCode": "6a5f9", "subCategoryCode": "13", "noteText": "INCOMING -20- aug demo", "dateCreated": "2020-08-19T20:03:35.1986907", "createdBy": "Mick", "dateUpdated": "2020-08-19T20:03:35.1986907", "updatedBy": "Mick", "attachmentId": "0xc2d174150x2625", "fileDescription": "test-FN-attachment-1-20-Aug", "authorId": "35651784012", "serviceFromDate": "2020-08-05T00:00:00", "serviceToDate": "2020-08-20T00:00:00", "dateOnDocument": "2020-08-11T00:00:00", "status": "ffe1c"}', 'filenote_id': '08D8447A', 'processed': 'false'}]

    print("ALL FAILED REQUESTS ------->" + str(failed_requests))

    for failed_request in failed_requests:
        print(
            failed_request["filenote_id"],
            ":",
            failed_request["payload"],
            failed_request["processed"],
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myfunction()
```

Prints:

```
ALL FAILED REQUESTS ------->[{'payload': '{"claimNumber": "9000005", "dateEntered": "2010-09-17T13:08:02", "fileNoteId": "08D8447A", "fileName": "responseUint.pdf.pdf", "fileExtension": ".pdf", "categoryCode": "6a5f9", "subCategoryCode": "13", "noteText": "INCOMING -20- aug demo", "dateCreated": "2020-08-19T20:03:35.1986907", "createdBy": "Mick", "dateUpdated": "2020-08-19T20:03:35.1986907", "updatedBy": "Mick", "attachmentId": "0xc2d174150x2625", "fileDescription": "test-FN-attachment-1-20-Aug", "authorId": "35651784012", "serviceFromDate": "2020-08-05T00:00:00", "serviceToDate": "2020-08-20T00:00:00", "dateOnDocument": "2020-08-11T00:00:00", "status": "ffe1c"}', 'filenote_id': '08D8447A', 'processed': 'false'}]
08D8447A : {"claimNumber": "9000005", "dateEntered": "2010-09-17T13:08:02", "fileNoteId": "08D8447A", "fileName": "responseUint.pdf.pdf", "fileExtension": ".pdf", "categoryCode": "6a5f9", "subCategoryCode": "13", "noteText": "INCOMING -20- aug demo", "dateCreated": "2020-08-19T20:03:35.1986907", "createdBy": "Mick", "dateUpdated": "2020-08-19T20:03:35.1986907", "updatedBy": "Mick", "attachmentId": "0xc2d174150x2625", "fileDescription": "test-FN-attachment-1-20-Aug", "authorId": "35651784012", "serviceFromDate": "2020-08-05T00:00:00", "serviceToDate": "2020-08-20T00:00:00", "dateOnDocument": "2020-08-11T00:00:00", "status": "ffe1c"} false
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should write

```
failed_request["filenote_id"],
failed_request["payload"],
```

not

```
failed_requests["file_note_id"],
failed_requests["payload"],
```